# check if there is a new element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have li that will be added dynamically by users, and there is a checkbox within the li. I want the text of li be the same color with the checkbox's color, the color of checkbox is random.

I tried play around but what I got is it changed all the li text color to one color..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('li:has(input:checkbox)').css('color','red');
```

Comment: the checkbox have 3 class for 3 set of color, but your code is still change all the li text to one color.. 

I thought of $(this).css().. but don;t have the complete picture

Comment: @JohannClemons well you can use .each to loop through the li which has checkbox and randomly add class to each of them